# Minikube cluster not responding

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

This is my current status of my minikube on my MAC.

```
minikube: Running
cluster: Stopped
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
```

when I tried running a 'minikube start' I get the below errors:

```
 Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
    Starting VM...
    E0919 14:31:51.762390   11784 start.go:159] Error starting host: 
    Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: Temporary Error: ssh 
    command error:
    command : sudo systemctl -f restart docker
    err     : Process exited with status 1
    output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process 
    exited with error code.
    See "systemctl  status docker.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

**Any pointers to the above problem's resolution will be great.**

Comment: Provide  information on how you installed minikube and provide related logs from journalctl.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to post how you got to that point. What hypervisor did you install? how did you install minikube?

In any case, it looks like you have an issue with the docker daemon in your minikube VM.  And from the looks, you are using Hyperkit/Docker for Mac since it's trying to connect to it using ssh.  I would wipe out minikube and Docker for Mac (completely remove it) and start from scratch. It looks like your Hyperkit VM cannot start the docker daemon, my guess it's using the wrong VM.

Hope it helps!